# How to obtain the user ID of the current profile being edited in WP-Admin?

Tags: admin, wp-admin, users, profiles, id

Is there a way of obtaining the user ID of the profile being edited in `wp-admin`?

I know it's in the URL if you are editing a user, EX: `./wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=427`. Could always `$_GET['user_id']` to retrieve the user's ID, but what about when you're editing your own profile in `wp-admin`? The user ID wouldn't be in the URL. EX `./wp-admin/profile.php`

Is there an easy or broad way of retrieving the user ID of the current user profile being edited in `wp-admin`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a global variable called … `$user_id` available on that page. Always.

From [`user-edit.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src//wp-admin/user-edit.php#L13):

```
$user_id = (int) $user_id;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( ! defined( 'IS_PROFILE_PAGE' ) )
    define( 'IS_PROFILE_PAGE', ( $user_id == $current_user->ID ) );

if ( ! $user_id && IS_PROFILE_PAGE )
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
elseif ( ! $user_id && ! IS_PROFILE_PAGE )
    wp_die(__( 'Invalid user ID.' ) );
elseif ( ! get_userdata( $user_id ) )
    wp_die( __('Invalid user ID.') );
```

Answer (score 3):

A little simplified. I didn't have access to a $user_id variable.

```
// If is current user's profile (profile.php)
if ( defined('IS_PROFILE_PAGE') && IS_PROFILE_PAGE ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
// If is another user's profile page
} elseif (! empty($_GET['user_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['user_id']) ) {
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
// Otherwise something is wrong.
} else {
    die( 'No user id defined.' );
}
```